# Gnuplot vector fortran

Tags: fortran, gnuplot, fortran90, gfortran

How do you plot this program(fortran) in vector form in gnuplot?? the command:

call execute_command_line("gnuplot plotvel.txt")  does not seem to work. Nothing happens

And what does using 1:2:3:4 mean?? in " plot "file.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors filled head lw 3 "

```
call execute_command_line("gnuplot plotvel.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are making a data file `plotdata.txt` at the beginning of the program, while trying to plot `file.dat` later, so that Gnuplot cannot find the latter. After fixing this, you can attach `-persist` option to keep the graph on the screen as

```
call execute_command_line("gnuplot -persist plotvel.txt")
```

Otherwise the graph disappears instantly and you cannot see the picture. Also, `using 1:2:3:4` means that you plot the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns in your data file. For  `vectors`, the first two represent the starting point of each vector and the last two the vector to be plotted. It is also OK to just omit `using 1:2:3:4` because it is the default for `vectors`. (In the graph below, I removed `xrange` and `yrange` to plot all the vectors.) [image]