# How to call a gnuplot script from Fortran

Tags: plot, scripting, fortran, gnuplot

I'm currently making a program which plots the orbit of the Planets/Moons around the Sun. I was just wondering how do I get my program to automatically call the script file and plot it?

```
    set xr [-2e11 : 2e11] #sets ranges 
    set yr [-2e11 : 2e11]
    set zr [-8e6 : 8e6]

    set xl 'x-distance (m)' #sets labels 
    set yl 'y-distance (m)'
    set zl 'z-distance (m)'

    set xtics(-1.5e11, -1e11, 0.5e11, 0, 0.5e11, 1e11, 1.5e11) #set labels of axis
    set ytics(-1.5e11, -1e11, -0.5e11, 0, 0.5e11, 1e11, 1.5e11)

    splot '3body_SEM_adv.dat' u 1:2:3 w l t "Earth's Orbit",\ #plots the file 
          '3body_SEM_adv.dat' u 7:8:9 w l t "Sun's Orbit",\
          '3body_SEM_adv.dat' u 13:14:15 w l t "Moon's Orbit"

    set term x11
```

Also when I run the script via the terminal, it closes automatically. Does anyone know why it's doing that?

The script file is currently called '3body_SEM_adv.plt' is the file extension correct, or should it be .gnu?

Comment: You have to set the terminal before `splot`, otherwise it has no effect. To prevent closing of the window when executing gnuplot, use the `persist` option: `set term x11 persist`. The extension of the file should have no effect.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807448/gnuplot-vector-fortran and other questions about gnuplot and Fortran.

Comment: I use gnuplot as well for my plotting, but use it via python. I find it very easy to integrate with python. Maybe it would be easier to call your fortran program and post-processing gnuplot script from python?

Comment: I'd have the fortran program print the data to stdout and let gnuplot read it from there. That way you don't have to rebuild your program every time you want to change a colour in the output. Plus you don't have a buildup of temporary files on your harddisk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36630991/4275259

Comment: Ah thanks! Do you know you how to call the script when the program is running, so I could ask the user how "Do you want to see the graph?", then if they say yes, the program would automatically run the script file and then put the graph to the screen? Thank you again! :D